# Does a Central Limit Theorem imply a series is $O(\sqrt{N})$?

Tags: pr.probability

The answer is probably well-known,  but I cannot find anything definite in the literature.

Suppose we have the usual ingredients of a CLT,  i.e. the series

$$X_N = \sum_{n=1}^N x_n $$

where $x_n$ are i.i.d.'s.     The CLT says that $X_N/ \sqrt{N}$  approaches a normal distribution.

Some of the literature states $X_N = O(\sqrt{N})$.   That's the interpretation I would like for my purposes!        But it seems more like the CLT implies it is $O(\sqrt{N})$ with probability equal to 1.    In mathematical physics,  we would be un-inclined to make such a distinction.   In pure math,   what is the rigorous way to state these things?     Are there any delicate issues involved?

Comment: As a mathematical physicist, I must protest: we would indeed be careful with such distinctions.  Maybe not a **theoretical** physicist.

Comment: It's not even $O(\sqrt{N})$ with probability 1. Do you know about the law of the iterated logarithm?

Comment: Let me refine the statement:   Does the CLT imply it is $O(\sqrt{N^{1/2+\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: Yes, it does; law of the iterated logarithm again.

Comment: I am getting two conflicting answers.    I better look up the iterated logarithm.

Comment: Christian,  can you clarify?     I'm interpreting your answer that it IS $O(\sqrt{N})$ with probability 1.   Is that right?

Comment: The CLT would seem to imply that it is of $O(N^{1/2+\epsilon})$ with probability =1  for any $\epsilon >0$.     So what is subtle?

Comment: Watch the quantifiers.  It's clear that CLT implies $O(N^{1/2+\epsilon})$ with **high** probability.  That is, for every $\epsilon$ and $C$ we have $P(|X_N| \le C N^{1/2+\epsilon}) \to 1$ as $N \to \infty$.  When you say "$O(N^{1/2+\epsilon"})$ with probability 1" I read that as "for $P$-almost every $\omega$, there exists $C = C(\omega)$ such that $|X_N(\omega)| \le C N^{1/2+\epsilon}$ for all $N$".  The latter statement is a lot stronger.  You could perhaps get it from a version of CLT with good bounds on the convergence rate, via Borel-Cantelli, but I don't think it's trivial.

Comment: But the latter statement is implied by the [LIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm).  LIL is substantially harder to prove than CLT, but at least in your iid finite-variance setting, it's a classical result.

Comment: In your notation, LIL says that $X_N$ is $O((N \log \log N)^{1/2})$ with probability $1$, and moreover this is sharp.

Comment: Thank you Nate.     I've received some very good answers on this site on questions I am just not an expert on.     This is very helpful since for my purposes I only need $O(\sqrt{N})$ up to logs anyway,   since the latter don't spoil the convergence of a series I am trying to establish.

Comment: @AndréLeClair: The party seems over here by now, but one more comment on your question above: even for a deterministic sequence $a_n=O(n^{1/2+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon>0$ will not imply that $a_n=O(n^{1/2})$ because the implied constant may depend on $\epsilon$ (trivial example: $a_n=n^{1/2}\log n$).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sharp general result in this direction is the classical [law of the iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm) (LIL).  Suppose, after renormalizing if necessary, that the $x_n$ are iid with zero mean and unit variance.  Then the LIL states that
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_N}{\sqrt{N \log \log N}} = \sqrt{2}, \quad \text{a.s.}$$
In your language, that says that with probability 1, $X_N$ is $O(\sqrt{N \log \log N})$, and that this cannot be improved to $O(\sqrt{N})$.

To be more careful, it says that for $P$-almost every $\omega$, there is a finite number $C(\omega)$ such that $|X_N(\omega)| \le C(\omega) \sqrt{N \log \log N}$ for all $N$.

LIL isn't a direct corollary of CLT, and I believe there are settings where either may hold while the other fails.  So I don't think it's true that the CLT "implies" the result you desire, but in any case they are both true in your setting.

Answer (score 6):

There is a notion "big O in probability" that may be what you are bumping up against in the literature. The notation (for a sequence $(Y_n)$ of random variables and a sequence $(b_n)$ of positive constants) $Y_n=O_P(b_n)$ means that the sequence $(Y_n/b_n)$ is *stochastically bounded*, in that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a cutoff $C>0$ such that $\Bbb P[|Y_n|/b_n>C]<\epsilon$ for all $n$. The CLT indeed implies that your sequence satisfies $X_N=O_P(\sqrt{N})$.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement, may be, the following statement citing from "R. I. Serfling, *Approximation Theorems of Mathematical Statistics*, John Wiley & Sons, 1980." is helpful for your question. 
[image]